# How do I increase quotas for Google Translate API?

Tags: google-api, google-translate

I am using the Google Translate API (for REST).  There is a quota of 2M characters/day.  I would like to increase that - how do I do so?
I have followed the instructions provided to no avail.

1. Google Developers Console
2. Select Project, Expand API & Auth, Click the Translate API, Go To
   Quota
3. I have clicked the 'Apply for higher quota' which returns a 'page
   not found' error
4. I have clicked each 'Change' button and input a higher number. 
   When Submitted it sits there; there is no response.

I have also gone to the API Console, and selected Quotas under my Project.  There is no link to 'Request more...' for the Translate API, as there is with other APIs.

Comment: That's a bug I am going to find someone at Google to report it to. Well spotted.  Its broken in the documentation as well https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/pricing

Comment: I also noticed an inconsistency.  Under the Developers Console, there is a Per User Limit of 100 Requests/User/Second.  However under the API Console > Quotas, it says the Per User Limit is 100 Characters/User/Second.  Which is correct?

Comment: Running into a similar issue even though I'm paying and the quotas have been set high - Have you found a solution? I've even added a sleep() of 5secs after 99 requests and still get the userRateLimitExceeded error

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug.  It also appears in the documentation.  https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/pricing.   Google has been informed they are in the process of tracking someone down to fix the issue with the file at this time.

**How To increase quota from the Console**

You can / or should be able to extend it from the console.

Go  APIs-> click on Translation API -> look for Quota click on that

[image]

You should be able to click on `Apply for Higher quota`.  But the link isn't working right now.   Google is on it.  I will update this when i hear from them that it has been fixed.

Again Well spotted, and thank you for pointing it out :)

**Update**: I was told by Google that you should be able to increase your quota by enabling billing.  There is also a thread about this on Google's Forums
[Change quota fails; Apply for higher quota URL is broken](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-translate-api/l2g7ws44B5k)

**Update 2 (direct from Google)**

> Fixes were pushed on February 27th, they include:
>
> - Telling the user on the Quota tab that they have to enable billing
> - Removing the option to  change the quota when billing isn't enabled
> - We no longer show a red warning triangle that 0% of 0 quota has been used
>
> What we haven't fixed is the link to the document on how to apply for a quota
>   increase, the bug for this has been bouncing backwards and forwards
>   but we seem to be closing in on a resolution.

Comment: I was told you should be able to increase it if you enable billing.

Comment: In theory you cannot even turn on Translate API without billing enabled, because the API is paid-only. But some people get stuck in a strange state and have to perform this step again. If you cannot enable billing, file a billing case -- no support plan needed. If you need more quota than you can select in the console, then you will need to talk to sales. You can use the form at https://cloud.google.com/contact/

Comment: Update: there is a quota request form specific to the Translate API at https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/translate_api_quota_request_form